# Проблемы с socket.async_accept() в boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Пишу асинхронный TCP сервер

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <clocale>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace std;

class tcp_server
{
private:
    ip::tcp::socket socket;
    ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    int clientCount = 0;
    int port = 0;
    enum { max_lenght = 256 };
    char buff[max_lenght];
public:
    tcp_server(io_service& service, int port) : socket(service), acceptor(service, ip::tcp::v4(), port)
    {
        this->port = port;
    }
    void do_accept()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, accept_handler);
    }
    void accept_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            // Accept succeeded.
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
        io_service service;
        tcp_server(service, 5000);
        service.run();
    }
    catch (exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "Исключение: " << ex.what();
        system("pause");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Однако получаю набор следующих ошибок
[image: Ошибка компиляции]

Как исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

```
acceptor.async_accept(
    socket, 
    [this](const boost::system::error_code& error) {
        this->accept_handler(error);
    }
);
```

Comment: Где мне об этом почитать? Вот я смотрел на оф. сайте как использовать функцию, но там ничего подобного нет.

Comment: @Герман проблема не относится непосредственно к функции async_accept. Вы пытаетесь "протолкнуть" в нее функцию-член, но она ожидает простую функцию, либо функциональный объект. В моем примере использовано лямбда-выражение, но можно использовать, например, boost::bind. Пример имеется в документации boost::asio: 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer4.html  
что касается корней проблемы, то Вам нужно познакомиться с функциональными объектами, а также с отличиями функций от функций-членов класса.

Comment: Если ТС не понял ваш ответ, то лучше дополнить его, а не писть развёрнутые комментарии.